# Array is not iterable at build time

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm building an app with Next using Typescript.

I'm passing an array of objects called "accordion" as a prop.

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'
import { NextPage } from 'next'

interface Section {
  header: string
  prompt: string
  linkRef: string
  linkTxt: string
  bs: string
  id: string
}
type Props = {
  accordion: Section[]
  children: any[]
}

const Accordion: NextPage<Props> = ({ accordion, children }) => {
  const [firstItem, ...otherItems] = accordion
  console.log(accordion)
  const others = otherItems.map((i: Section, index: number) => (
    <div key={nanoid()} className="accordion-item">
      <h2 className="accordion-header" id={`heading${i.bs}`}>
        <button
          className="accordion-button"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target={`#collapse${i.bs}`}
          aria-expanded="true"
          aria-controls={`collapse${i.bs}`}
        >
          {i.header} &rarr;
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div
        id={`collapse${i.bs}`}
        className="accordion-collapse collapse"
        aria-labelledby={`heading${i.bs}`}
        data-bs-parent="#main"
      >
        <section id={i.id} className="accordion-body">
          <div>{children[index + 1]}</div>
          <div>
            {i.prompt}
            <Link href={i.linkRef}>
              <a>{i.linkTxt}</a>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  ))

  return (
    <div key={nanoid()} className="accordion" id="main">
      <div className="accordion-item">
        <h2 className="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
          <button
            className="accordion-button"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#collapseOne"
            aria-expanded="true"
            aria-controls="collapseOne"
          >
            {firstItem.header} &rarr;
          </button>
        </h2>
        <div
          id="collapseOne"
          className="accordion-collapse collapse"
          aria-labelledby="headingOne"
          data-bs-parent="#main"
        >
          <section id={firstItem.id} className="accordion-body">
            <div className="mdxContainer">{children[0]}</div>
            <div>
              {firstItem.prompt}
              <Link href={firstItem.linkRef}>
                <a>{firstItem.linkTxt}</a>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
      {others}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Accordion
```

In development, Typescript strict mode detects no errors and "accordion" serves it's purpose.

But at build time, it says the array is not iterable.

This happens during the step which generates static pages.

EDIT: All logs show an array for accordion and otherItems, both of type object, both of which return true for Array.isArray(accordion)

Comment: Your type system is safe to your compile time code, but a static site generator build step involves real data from remote sources. Are you 1000% positive you are passing an array in for your data in all scenarios? What if a page has an error, user formatted it wrong, etc. Filter out invalid inputs and see if your page builds. Consider a system to detect/gracefully fail so one bad doc doesn't wipe the site out (or do, it's fine.. failures don't promote )

Comment: can you add log for otherItems

Comment: Before restructuring the array log accordion and typeof accordion, You will be able find the issue

Comment: Well... The code was fine all along-- every refactored version.  When using an opinionated framework for the first time, always learn it's opinions about your file structure.  I didn't realize my UI components were nested in my pages directory.  